# springboot with MongoDb ,Transient field return null

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregate, transient

When i trying to do my RBAC job , I've made a class `RolePermission` like belows:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RolePermission extends BaseEntity{
    private Long roleId;
    private Long permissionId;
    @Transient
    private List<Permission> permissions;
    public RolePermission(Long roleId,Long permissionId){
        this.roleId = roleId;
        this.permissionId = permissionId;
    }
}
```

class `Permission` like belows

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Permission extends BaseEntity{

    public Permission(Long id, Long parentId, String name){
        this.setId(id);
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.name = name;
    }
    private String name;
    private Long parentId;
    private String url;
    private String permission;
    private Integer type;
    private String icon;
    private Integer status;
    private Integer ord;
}
```

Here comes my test :

```java
LookupOperation lookup = Aggregation.lookup("permission", "roleId", "_id", "permissions");
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookup);
        AggregationResults<RolePermission> role_permission = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "role_permission", RolePermission.class);
        //AggregationResults<Map> role_permission = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "role_permission", Map.class);
        System.out.println(role_permission.getMappedResults());
        //userService.getAllPermissions(u);
```

When I add `@Transient` , `permissions` comes to `null`
[image]

and When I remove `@Transient`,`permissions` comes back.
[image]

I don't wanna save `permissions` to MongoDB, so I add `@Transient`, is there any way i can draw the data back without saving it to the Database. Because I get the permissions data from a relationship collection`RolePermission`,not itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Transient` behaves similar to the `transient` keyword.

`transient` is used to denote that a field is not to be serialized (and therefore not saved in the database too).

`@Transient` is used to denote that a field should not persisted in database (but it is still serializable as java object).

Take look this baeldung tutorial for it: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-transient-ignore-field

There is no way to draw the data back without saving it to the Database because it isn't persisted at all since it is what `@Transient` is used for.

To get the data back you have to persist it somewhere else, but the best place is in the database. If you don't want to persist it along with the other data, consider saving it in a sperate database. So, you could split user data and authentication/RBAC data.

Comment: Thanks for your help . After reading the tutorial, I'm considering persisting my rbac data in mysql .